# SQL expand column value based on ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table with :

```
GroupID | Name
 1      | "a"
 2      | 
 2      | "b"
 1      | 
 1      |
```

I would like to expand all Name values to every line that has the same GroupID :

```
GroupID | Name
 1      | "a"
 2      | "b"
 2      | "b"
 1      | "a"
 1      | "a"
```

Is there a way to do that easily ?

Comment: `1      | "a"` and `1      | "d"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to *view* your data this way, then use `MAX` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT GroupID, MAX(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID) AS Name
FROM yourTable;
```

If instead you actually want to *update* your table, then use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET Name = (SELECT MAX(Name) FROM yourTable t WHERE t.GroupID = yourTable.GroupID)
WHERE Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: I don't understand this part : `FROM yourTable t WHERE t.GroupID = yourTable.GroupID` what does this do ?

Comment: This is the logic which _correlates_ each record in the outer query with all records belonging to the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, like your sample data there is only 1 Name for each GroupID, use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET Name = (SELECT MAX(t2.Name) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.GroupID = t1.GroupID)
WHERE t1.Name IS NULL
```